# Objective C: Cell.ImageView.image size Inconsistent

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I have a tableview which displays an image that is obtained from a server (via URL)

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:avatar_url] 
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

However, I am faced with the problem of inconsistent sizing of the image displayed in my cell. (see screenshots below):

[image]

[image]

1) How can I fix the size of the images retrieved?

2) How can I fix the cell.imageView's frame's size? Doing the following does not seem to work (cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,32,32).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the contentMode of the cell's Imageview

like this,

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = /*(something from the below list)*/;

typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

Comment: I tried to use the 'UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill', it worked for some cases. It seems like the frame size I set for the imageView does not work (cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,32,32)) as the image displayed is bigger than the frame. Is there a way to set the cell's imageview?

Comment: you can add a new image view on the contentView of cell.

Comment: does that mean I need to create additional subviews for my labels and subtitles as well? I was hoping that the standard cell.imageview was able to work properly i.e. display images of consistent size, esp when I tried to set the frame of the imageview.

Comment: but if I do that, the uiimage will overlap with my cell.textlabel and cell.detailTextLabel contents. Anyway to shift the labels to the right without requiring to recreate the labels?

Comment: There is a frame property for titleLabel and subtitlelabel that you can edit.